# Strange character appearing in MySQL database field

Tags: mysql, database, import, filemaker

I've imported some data from an old FileMaker program into a mysql database and I've noticed some strange characters. What is the best way to get rid of all these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check character encoding

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: You seem to use an editor. The imported data have to be encoded the same way as your table character encoding

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data you imported into your MySQL DB has a different character set (Collation) then what you set when you built the table in MySQL.

My guess would be those "strange characters" are an emoji.   Which for example in utf8 charset, aren't defined.  But utf8mb4 they would be.

The short answer is, find what charset the data was originally made in, and build your new data table with the same charset.

**MySQL Workbench**

The Charset can be manipulated easily in MySQL Workbench by right clicking the schema then table in question, click on the wrench.

**SQL Syntax**

Or via something similar to :

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE YourTableName modify name text charset utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your varchar length are overflowing.

For example: field varchar(10) and you put "STRING OVER 10 CHARACTERS" this may cause trash on String.